# Alternatives of repeatedly using elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion

Im trying to return the 'students' grades according to what they got on python. I used a bunch of elif statements but i dont feel like this is efficient. I was wondering if there are any other ways i can present this as? possibly smaller. Ive attempted using for loops and dictionaries, but im not getting it, maybe cuz i dont understand dictionaries well loll

```
def grade_select(grade):
    if grade <  40: return "D-"
    elif grade <= 40 and grade < 45: return "D"
    elif grade <= 45 and grade < 50: return "D+"
    elif grade <= 50 and grade < 55: return "C-"
    elif grade <= 55 and grade < 60: return "C"
    elif grade <= 60 and grade < 65: return "C+"
    elif grade <= 65 and grade < 70: return "B-"
    elif grade <= 70 and grade < 75: return "B"
    elif grade <= 75 and grade < 80: return "B+"
    elif grade <= 80 and grade < 85: return "A-"
    elif grade <= 85 and grade < 90: return "A" 
    elif grade >= 90: return "A+"
```

Comment: Check out the keyword "Switch"

Comment: use a dictionary with ranges and letters

Comment: @d6stringer Python doesn't really have a switch statement, it has pattern matching though, but that doesn't really give you any advantage over this `if...elif...elif` branching

Comment: This is fine. There is nothing really wrong with this

Comment: @Matiiss how would that work?

Comment: ***Python 3.10*** provides a `match ... case` syntax you could try out.

Comment: @Just5MoreMinutes what advantage would that provide here?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga right, my bad.. they just introduced "match" and "case" though which is the same idea.

Comment: @Just5MoreMinutes How would i use match and cases? in this case and does it not take the same amount of space as if/elifs?

Comment: @quadinglethe2nd it does. Again, your code is fine (I would just format it according to PEP8)

Comment: your comparitions make no sense: `grade <= 40 and grade < 45` means the same as `grade <= 40` - you need `>=` instead of `<=`.  to get `grade >= 40 and grade < 45` which means `40 <= grade < 45` but with this order of `if/elif` you can skip `grade >= 40`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga as far as I know it's faster than your regular `if ... elif ... else` statement

Comment: @Just5MoreMinutes it is not. Why would it be?

Comment: Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We expect questions to be written properly here, as if you were helping to build a library of searchable questions (that is the purpose of posting), not as if you were talking to a friend about the code on Discord.

Answer (score 3):

since you return when a condition is matched, you do not need to use `elif` just `if`.

moreover, the previous condition eliminates the need of checking if the value is "between".

```
def grade_select(grade):
    if grade < 40: return "D-"
    if grade < 45: return "D"
    if grade < 50: return "D+"
    if grade < 55: return "C-"
    if grade < 60: return "C"
    if grade < 65: return "C+"
    if grade < 70: return "B-"
    if grade < 75: return "B"
    if grade < 80: return "B+"
    if grade < 85: return "A-"
    if grade < 90: return "A" 
    return "A+"
```

an alternative would be to declare a dictionary and calculate where the grade fits.

```
grades = { 40: "D-", 45: "D", 50: "D+", 55: "C-", 60: "C", 65: "C+", 70: "B-", 75: "B", 80: "B+", 85: "A-", 90: "A", 100: "A+" }

def grade_select(grade):
    grade = (grade // 5 * 5) + 5

    if grade < 40:
        grade = 40
    elif grade > 90:
        grade = 100

    return grades[grade]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to store the range and it's according grade value:

```py
def grade_select(grade):
    dct = {
        range(0, 40): "D-",
        range(40, 45): "D",
        range(45, 50): "D+",
        ...
        range(90, 100 + 1): "A+"
    }
    dct = {g: m for r, m in dct.items() for g in r}
    return dct[grade]
```

Comment: How is this better or more efficient? This forces you to iterate over every item, it doesn't even exit early

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's an alternative, also I'd say it's more readable

Comment: If you are going to do this, then the dictionary should probably be a global variable

Comment: yeah, could be, but unless it's used a bunch elsewhere (which I doubt because otherwise what's the point of that function), it's not like it would be a bottleneck anyways

Comment: True, it is all fundamentally constant time

Answer (score 1):

Well, your condition is kinda weird, because

```
elif grade <= 40 and grade < 50
```

has no sense (if grade <= 40 then grade < 50 of course)

But I think you wanna write something like this:

```
if 40 <= grade < 50:
    pass
```

You can use syntax above, it could make it a little bit better.
Also, you can check  [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/3-alternatives-to-if-statements-to-make-your-python-code-more-readable-91a9991fb353)

Comment: oh oops yeah thats on me, i meant elif grade >=40 and grade < 50

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fastest version that calculates an index based on the grade value. This method only works if your grade ranges are all five wide.

```
_lettergrades = ['D-', 'D', 'D+', 'C-', 'C', 'C+', 'B-', 'B', 'B+', 'A-', 'A', 'A+']

def grade_select(grade):  
    return _lettergrades[(max(min(grade, 90), 35) - 35) // 5]
```

If your ranges weren't consistently five wide you could use [`bisect.bisect_right`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) to get an index for the letter grade. The search uses bisection, which should be faster than a linear search. (The lists `_thresholds` and `_lettergrades` are global to avoid recreating them for every call to `grade_select()`.)

```
from bisect import bisect_right
    
_thresholds = [40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90]
_lettergrades = ['D-', 'D', 'D+', 'C-', 'C', 'C+', 'B-', 'B', 'B+', 'A-', 'A', 'A+']

def grade_select(grade):
    return _lettergrades[bisect_right(_thresholds, grade)]
```

**Note:** I doubt speed matters as much as clarity here. For clarity I like Paulo Pereira's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73777830/1322401) best.

Answer (score -1):

I guess using dictionary is the best way

```
def grade_select(grade):
    d = {
        'D-':range(0,40),
        'D':range(45,50),
        'D+':range(50,55),
        'C-':range(55,60) #, etc.
    }

    return [k for k,v in d.items() if grade in v][0]
```

Comment: Returning a list is wrong. You could use a plain for-loop instead: `for k,v in d.items(): if grade in v: return k`

Comment: @wjandrea you're right, I was inattentive.  but I guess list comprehention is still better (and faster) than for loop, we just need to add `[0]` to get rid of list.  `return [k for k,v in d.items() if grade in v][0]`

Comment: Better how? It's harder to read and it can't return early. The plain for-loop is in fact better.

Comment: I'm wrong for loop would be better for this situation